# Why is MySQL creating tables with a _seq suffix?

Tags: mysql

I have created a InnoDB table named `foo` in MySQL. As soon as I perform an insert into the table, I see that another table `foo_seq` is created.

If I drop the auto generated table, it appears after the next insert.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a sequence is being created, do you have any autogenerated primary keys or IDs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "autogenerated", I have auto incrementing primary key on the table.

Comment: Since when does MySQL have sequences?

Comment: @mmattax That's basically a autogenerated value.

Answer (score 2):

Issue this query, chances are *very* high it will tell you what happens before an insert:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'foo';
```