# Why does phpMyAdmin add "_seq" after my table name? And there are no properties other than next_val

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, phpmyadmin

I'm learning Spring, trying to work with a server (MySQL), created a server using MOMP, connected to the project, but when I try to open the page where the server is used, I get an undefined error. The only difference between my project and the tutorial's project is that there the table is created without "_seq" and there are properties in "structure".

How do I add a table to the database using MySQL, so that it does not turn into a "*_seq"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is the value SQL will use to auto increment keys for tables that contain id fields that are auto-generated (say, by hibernate).  The typical value is 1, which means each auto-generated id will simply be the next integer.  I assume you have a library managing your db instance.

See this related post -- [Why is MySQL creating tables with a _seq suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866699/why-is-mysql-creating-tables-with-a-seq-suffix)

See this simple example here -- https://www.mysqltutorial.net/mysql-sequence/

Cheers!